# Why the pcap file always shows more bytes downloaded than the actual file size downloaded when using wireshark?

Tags: wireshark, pcap

When capturing a dump using wireshark during download of a file and then exploring the total bytes downloaded in pcap is always greater than the actual file downloaded.

for example

700000 bytes shows in pcap

680000 bytes shows in original file size

Comment: This is simply a false assumption. I am looking at a Wireshark capture at the moment where Wireshark shows bytes captured as 392,187 and the file size is 493,132.

Comment: so why is the difference?

Comment: Because data on the wire is not the same as data stored to disk by an application. Why can you save the same document in your favorite word processing in a variety of different formats and they have different sizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just protocol overhead. YOur file is cut into  smaler bites,
gets tcp header, gets ip header, gets ethernet header ...

Comment: Got the point that's correct.